# SwiftUI: is possible Gesture var move into EnvironmentObject?

Tags: swiftui, gesture, modifier

I am not familiar with SWIFTUI and closure. Here move some gesture code to extension function, except var drag.
For Gesture, Is is possible to move the drag into environmentObject? How to initialize ?

```
class ViewState:ObservableObject {
    @Published  var isDragging = false
    @Published  var size: CGFloat = 100.0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var  viewState:ViewState=ViewState()

    var drag:some Gesture { isDrag(viewState) }

    var body: some View {
       Circle()
           .fill(viewState.isDragging ? Color.red: Color.blue)
           .frame(width:viewState.size, height:viewState.size, alignment: .center)
            .gesture(drag)
        
     }
}


extension ContentView {
    func isDrag(_ viewState:ViewState)->some Gesture {
          DragGesture()
             .onChanged {_ in
                viewState.isDragging = true
                viewState.size += 10.0
             }
             .onEnded{_ in
                viewState.isDragging = false
                viewState.size = 100.0
            }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Done, Closure is function! Now, I can move this code to other views, but still update with view risk. and declared data (environmentObject) is not independent.

```
class ViewState:ObservableObject {
    @Published  var isDragging = false
    @Published  var size: CGFloat = 100.0
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var  viewState:ViewState=ViewState()

   // var drag:some Gesture { }

    var body: some View {
       Circle()
           .fill(viewState.isDragging ? Color.red: Color.blue)
           .frame(width:viewState.size, height:viewState.size, alignment: .center)
           .isDragged(viewState)
        
     }
}


extension View {
    func drag(_ viewState:ViewState)->some Gesture {
          DragGesture()
             .onChanged {_ in
                viewState.isDragging = true
                viewState.size += 10.0
             }
             .onEnded{_ in
                viewState.isDragging = false
                viewState.size = 100.0
            }
         }
     

    @ViewBuilder func isDragged(_ viewState:ViewState) -> some View {
        self.gesture(drag(viewState))
    }
}
```